# Is there anything outside of projection and modelView matix to effect a vertex postion?

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4

**Update/conclusion:**
Just to save you some time. After looking at my matrix code 100 times over I was confident that my problem was a configuration/OpenGL call I was missing, but after my back and forth with Prabindh, I may be wrong with that assumption. So for now the answer is **NO, there isn't any setup calls that I missed that resulted in the stretched cube and it may just be a bad matrix.** I will update this question when the bug is solved. Since the bug is not within the scope of this question, I'll leave it at that and post a link when I have the true source of my bug.

**Solution to problem:**
For anyone having a similar problem of a stretched shape, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234226/whats-different-with-my-lookat-and-perspective-calls-vs-gluperspective-and-gllo/25464916#25464916) thread  solved my problem.

**Clarification:**
I'm not asking what's wrong with my code, but what to look for outside of what I already looked at that would cause the bug I'm seeing. I'm seeing what should be a cube, appear as a recatangular box (see screen shot). So the question I'm asking is: **Assuming a fixed pipeline (no shaders), and both matrix are correct and CONSTANT (not calling glTranslate, push, pop, etc....); outside of what I checked, what could cause the cube to stretch along the depth?** Below is a description of the setup and what I've checked. Please let me know

**About the code:**

- Both matrix are NOT pushed or popped
- Both are generated and loaded (not using gluperspective() or glLookAt())

  - Generated matrix are based on opengl function documentation
- No changes (such as translations) are done to the matrix beyond updating both on screen resize
- The cube is drawn with triangles via a series of vertex calls (see below code).

> glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
>       glColor4f(0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
>       glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);//top
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glColor4f(0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f);
>       glNormal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);//bottom
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glColor4f(0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
>       glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//right
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glColor4f(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
>       glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);//left
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glColor4f(1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f);
>       glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);//front
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z+1.0f);
>       glColor4f(1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
>       glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);//back
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y+1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x-1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glVertex3f(pt.x+1.0f, pt.y-1.0f, pt.z-1.0f);
>       glEnd();

**What I've checked:**

- When generating the perspective matrix, angle is in radians (math functions are in radians)
- Viewport is kept up to date
- Perspective matrix is kept up to date with screen ratio (I just update both matrix anyway)
- The correct matrix is loaded to the correct matrix type
- Matrix generating call is a match to the documentation (glLookAt & gluPerspective)
- Checked cube drawing function (see code above)
- Array order of matrix is correct.=

**Prabindh**, I've done that in the past with zero success. I'm trying something different by asking what have I not looked at yet? instead of "here's code, what's wrong with it"...

In past attempts, I've posted segments of code and a link to a zip file with all the code, but either I'd get feed back about not seeing an issue or the thread died with zero feedback.

---

**Original Post:**
I'm trying to solve a bug where objects are stretched towards the background. At this point, I'm sure both Projection and Model View matrix are correct, after the 1000th time I've debugged it. What else can manipulate a vertex position assuming both matrix are correct, no shader has been set up and the viewport is kept up to date?

FYI, both matrix are just loaded rather than using calls like glLookAt() or gluperspective(), but logic-wise they're identical to those functions. I noticed if I modify the look at function to use a forward vector (third row of matrix) with a magnitude of 0.05, the problem is reduced, but that's just a hack to a bigger problem. **Also when I say "identical to the documentation", that's prior to playing with the numbers.**

[Screen Shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Pc7rf6Deuhc2JEa3ctOFpxbmc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The question is not clear - there can be many variables here, atleast provide the source code so that reviewers can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed-function vertex transformation is well-specified:

1. Object space to eye space, That's solely defined by the ModelView matrix and the `xyzw` object space position of the input vertices. You seem to use `glVertex3f`, so input `w` will be 1.
2. Eye space to clip space. Controlled by the Projection matrix.
3. Clip space to ndc. This only depends on the clip space coords, since it will simply divide `xyz` by `w`. Indirectly, the projection matrix will affect this step by making clip space `w` a function of the eye space `xyz` coords (typically just `z`).
4. NDC to screen space. For `xy`, the viewport settings will be relevant. For `z`, the transformation is controlled by `glDepthRange()`

So the only thing I mentioned which you did not check is the depth range, but it will not affect the 2D positions of the primitives in window space - you might only be able to screw up the depth test with that.

> I noticed if I modify the look at function to use a forward vector
>   with a magnitude of 0.05, the problem is reduced, but that's just a
>   hack to a bigger problem.

That is a very strong hint that your matrices are just *wrong*. It is also a contradicting that statement:

> FYI, both matrix are just loaded rather than using calls like
>   glLookAt() or gluperspective(), but logic-wise they're identical to
>   those functions.

Apart from floating point precision issues - and the obvious singularity if you get the null vector as forwad direction -`gluLookAt` will always produce the same matrix if you only change the lenght of the forward looking vector. Your code is definitively not identical to what `gluLookAt()` does.

Comment: Thanks Derhass, I just want to make sure we're on the same page: 1) there isn't some config I'm overlooking that would cause this bug and 2) this looks to be purely an error on the matrix (and likely a precision error)?  Also on a side note: yes, that "hack" did go counter to the equation shown in the documentation, but when undone it is identical. The difference being whether or not I multiply the third row of the matrix by a magnitude or not.

Comment: That does not look like any precision error. That looks like either you set up the matrices so that it _should_ look the way it does, or your matrix functions are just wrong. Since you give no details on what projection parameters your use, or how you calculate and apply those matrices, chances are very low that anyone can figure out what is going on.

Comment: Well at this point, it narrows the scope of my bug and answers the question of "did I leave any rock unturned". Derhass, since you seem confident that it is the matrix, that'll be my next question (thread).