# What's different with my lookAt and perspective calls VS gluPerspective and glLookat (cube stretched)

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4

**Side note: hey everyone, if you found my question/answer helpful, please don't forget to up vote. I kind of need it...**

So there seems to be something different with my implementation of both matrix [projection and model] (other than the stuff I've commented out for debugging purposes). Below is a screenshot of the bug I see when drawing a cube. **Keep in mind I do keep the viewport and matrix up to date with the window size and calculate screen ratio with float and not int, so don't bother asking, I've checked the usual suspects.....**

[Screen Shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Pc7rf6Deuhc2JEa3ctOFpxbmc/edit?usp=sharing)

[Files (linux build, see readme in ./build)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Pc7rf6DeuhNjhXNUFxSmpsbnM/edit?usp=sharing)
side note: while debugging, I've changed the cube's distance. To reproduce the screen shot, on line 76 of workspace.cpp set mDistance to about 90 and stretch the window frame to dimensions noted at lower right corner of the window.

**Please keep in mind the screen shot and the debug text output are seperate events as I'm constantly debugging this problem and getting new numbers.**

**The code:**

```
#define _AP_MAA 0
#define _AP_MAB 1
#define _AP_MAC 2
#define _AP_MAD 3
#define _AP_MBA 4
#define _AP_MBB 5
#define _AP_MBC 6
#define _AP_MBD 7
#define _AP_MCA 8
#define _AP_MCB 9
#define _AP_MCC 10
#define _AP_MCD 11
#define _AP_MDA 12
#define _AP_MDB 13
#define _AP_MDC 14
#define _AP_MDD 15
```

Setting up the camera perspective:

```
void APCamera::setPerspective(GMFloat_t fov, GMFloat_t aspect, GMFloat_t near, GMFloat_t far)
{
   GMFloat_t difZ = near - far;

   GMFloat_t *data;

   mProjection->clear(); //set to identity matrix
   data = mProjection->getData();

   GMFloat_t v = 1.0f / tan(fov / 2.0f);

   data[_AP_MAA] = v / aspect;
   data[_AP_MBB] = v;
   data[_AP_MCC] = (far + near) / (difZ);
   data[_AP_MCD] = -1.0f;
   data[_AP_MDD] = 0.0f;
   data[_AP_MDC] = (2.0f * far * near)/ (difZ);

   mRatio = aspect;

   mInvProjOutdated = true;
   mIsPerspective = true;
}
```

Setting up the camera direction:

```
bool APCamera::lookTo(Coordinate &to, Coordinate &from, Coordinate &up)  
 {
      Coordinate f, unitUp, right;  
      GMFloat_t *data;

      CoordinateOp::diff(&to, &from, &f);
      VectorOp::toUnit(&f, &f);
      VectorOp::toUnit(&up, &unitUp);
      VectorOp::cross(&f, &unitUp, &right);

      if((fabs(right.x) < FLOAT_THRESHOLD) && (fabs(right.y) < FLOAT_THRESHOLD) && (fabs(right.z) < FLOAT_THRESHOLD))
     {
         return false;
     }

     mCamPt = from;

     VectorOp::toUnit(&right, &mRight);
     mForward = f;
     VectorOp::cross(&mRight, &mForward, &mUp);

     mModelView->clear();
     data = mModelView->getData();

     data[_AP_MAA] = mRight.x;
     data[_AP_MBA] = mRight.y;
     data[_AP_MCA] = mRight.z;

     data[_AP_MAB] = mUp.x;
     data[_AP_MBB] = mUp.y;
     data[_AP_MCB] = mUp.z;

     data[_AP_MAC] = -mForward.x;
     data[_AP_MBC] = -mForward.y;
     data[_AP_MCC] = -mForward.z;

     //translation part is commented out to narrow bugs down, "camera" is kept at the center (0,0,0)
     //data[_AP_MDA] = (data[_AP_MAA] * -mCamPt.x) + (data[_AP_MBA] * -mCamPt.y) + (data[_AP_MCA] * -mCamPt.z);
     //data[_AP_MDB] = (data[_AP_MAB] * -mCamPt.x) + (data[_AP_MBB] * -mCamPt.y) + (data[_AP_MCB] * -mCamPt.z);
     //data[_AP_MDC] = (data[_AP_MAC] * -mCamPt.x) + (data[_AP_MBC] * -mCamPt.y) + (data[_AP_MCC] * -mCamPt.z);

  mInvViewOutdated = true;
  return true;
}
```

**The debug output:**

**LookTo() From:<0,0,0> To:<-1,0,0>:**
0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
1.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

**setPerspective() fov:0.785398 ratio:1.185185 near:0.500000 far:100.000000:**
2.036993 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 2.414213 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 -1.010050 -1.005025
0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000

Comment: Your matrices actually look fine.

Comment: So....   where to from here? The last question you answered implied it was the matrix.

Comment: It might be something inbeetween. Or the way the matrices are applied. You once mentioned you had pasted/linked the full source code somewhere. I haven't seen this. But I would have a look.

Comment: I've attached a link to the files. It's a bit of a mess, hopefully the readme in the build folder is of some help.....

Comment: did you check for matrix transposition when loading into opengl?

Comment: @Mr.UNOwen: OK, had a quick look. I was not able to reproduce that distorted image in your screenshot. All I get is a cube which is relatively close and reasonably distorted by the perspective. How do you get the situation as depicted in the screenshot?

Comment: On line 76 of workspace.cpp set mDistance to about 90 (don't recall the exact). From the screen shot I see that the width is set to 3815.

Comment: @derhass: any developments, can you reproduce it?

Comment: @Mr.UNOwen: yeah. I did check it. And now I'm convinced - everything is fine. It is just your extreme high aspect ratio. This is actually the result you should be seeing. The distortion will be extreme - your horzional vield of view will approach near 180 degress. What makes this "feel" unnatural is just the way you move your cube with the mouse, with the same speed, while actually, the object has to move nonlinearily more in world space as it approaches the borders. I think what you try to achieve could be better achieved by adjusting horizontol or vertical FOV, depending on the aspect ratio.

Comment: @derhass: I have a few questions then. 1. What would be the ratio to FOV conversion? 2. Adjusting the FOV doesn't seem to solve/explain the weird mouse tracking issue I'm having where the mouse eventually out races the cube. Just to save you some time going through the code. I get the mouse position in world by projecting a point that would be at the center at the given depth, getting the W and Z term from it and then unprojecting the mouse with the produced W & Z term and the mouse X and Y with regards to what its projected value would be. Is this the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: @Mr.UNOwen: 1. The horizontal FOV will be `2.0 * atan(  tan(fov_v/2.0) * aspect)`. 2. I think you screw up by using z _and_ w. The w part will also distort x and y, too. YOu should just take some euclidian 3d point and set w to 1, unproject that and divide by the resulting w. But that is only my first guess. I think you should open another question for that one.

Comment: That equation was close, but it seems 2.0f * atan(tan(DEFAULT_FOV_RAD/mRatio) * mRatio) does the job better. The cube stays the same size regardless of the screen ratio (but shrink and grows over the net size of the screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it looks like the trouble maker was just the FOV. **So the quick answer is NO I didn't do anything different from the documented perspective and look at function.** For anyone having a similar problem `2.0f * atan(tan(DEFAULT_FOV_RAD/mRatio) * mRatio)` did the job for me.